# Intellij IDEA is Slow,Compilation is slow and is consuming high memory

Tags: intellij-idea, memory-management, intellij-idea-2018

[My Memory Usage i have no idea why IDEA is using two **JAVA(SE) Platform Binary**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjpQj.jpg)

Comment: You can always switch to Eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ, like many IDEs has loads of features and capabilities. Not to mention, lots of plugins.

Sometimes taking a look through what extraneous stuff you have installed over the course of its use is the best bet.

Also, make sure your SDK is up to date.  If I remember correctly,  there is IntelliJ version that is downloadable with idea. Or of course you can always download your appropriate SDK from Java's website.

Finally, if all that looks in order. Backing up your configs and doing a reinstall will often fix misconfigurations.